# Как остановить поток main, пока все ArrayBlockingQueue не выполнятся?

Tags: java, многопоточность, concurrency

Как остановить поток `main`, пока все `ArrayBlockingQueue` не выполнятся?
То есть, существует main поток в котором я запускаю другие потоки для выполнения в которых используется `ArrayBlockingQueue`. Когда я использую `join` то `main` останавливается, но потоки с `ArrayBlockingQueue` судя по всему должны останавливаться, но main не продолжает потом работу вообще. Если пользуюсь `ThreadPoolExecutor` и `future` то тоже самое. Но если `main` не остановить то он продолжает работу и конечно завершается на много раньше.

В дебаге вижу что потоки "потребители" просто переходят в wait. так как

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            List<SimpleContent> docs = queue.take();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы остановить `main` и по завершению `ArrayBlockingQueue` `main` продолжал работу?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (QueueProps queueProps : queues) {
        BlockingQueue<List<SimpleContent>> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1);
        QueuePerformer queuePerformer = new QueuePerformer(blockingQueue);
        queuePerformer.setName(queueProps.getQueueSuffix());
        queuePerformer.start();
        QueueSender queueSender = new QueueSender(blockingQueue);
        queueSender.setName(queueProps.getQueueSuffix());
        queueSender.start();
    }

    setTime();
    //и так далее......
}
```

Comment: [Покажите ваш код.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev поправил

Comment: QueuePerformer - это Thread?

Comment: @MoS1993 Да, я еще раз поправил...

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для этого `ExecutorService` и `Callable` вот вам простой пример

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    List<Callable<String>> todo = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        todo.add(new Task());
    }
    List<Future<String>> results = executorService.invokeAll(todo);
    System.out.println("Finished...");
}

static class Task implements Callable<String> {

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " finished.");
        return "some-data";
    }
}
```

Вот результат этой программы:

> pool-1-thread-1 finished.
>
> pool-1-thread-2 finished.
>
> pool-1-thread-3 finished.
>
> pool-1-thread-4 finished.
>
> pool-1-thread-5 finished.
>
> pool-1-thread-6 finished.
>
> pool-1-thread-7 finished.
>
> pool-1-thread-8 finished.
>
> pool-1-thread-9 finished.
>
> pool-1-thread-10 finished.
>
> Finished...

Как написано в *JavaDocs* к методу invokeAll() - **Выполняет все задачи, возвращает список *Futures* которые хранят в себе статус и результаты когда все выполняться.**

PS если вам не надо получать данные из потоком имплементируйте интерфейс `Runnable` вместо `Callabe` и обверните все это так:

```
Executors.callable(new Task());
```

Comment: У меня ArrayBlockingQueue

Answer (score 0):

Выполните `join()` метод класса `Thread`, чтобы подождать, пока поток завершит свое выполнение.

```
queuePerformer.join();
queueSender.join();
```

Comment: Я уже писал что это не работает

Comment: while (true) - из этого цикла нет выхода?

Comment: Да, надо как-то нормально выйти из после завершения Consumer

Comment: вобще для таких целей используют 2 потока (Producer, Consumer) и методы wait(), notify(), notifyAll()

Comment: Вообще для таких целей сейчас используют блокирующие очереди, а не это убожество.